# How to display a block in lightbox 2

Tags: blocks, views, javascript

How to display a block inside lightbox 2 in d7.

i have views exposed filters as a block and i am trying to display it inside lightbox2 ... any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you lookup http://alldrupal.blogspot.in/2011/09/how-to-display-webforms-in-colorbox-in.html ?

Comment: it is not the same ... i do not want to use colorbox ... but any way thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: I think what Rupesh pointed to is your best bet, and can be adapted easily to lightbox2. Here's a link to some info on inline lightbox2: https://drupal.org/node/276378  .